# Rewrite with htaccess only category into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just want to change one word in my URL from latin to cyrillic. It is a WordPress product which is set to "product" in admin panel by old devs. They developed the website with their own shopping cart module and for some reason if I change "product" to "продукт" in the admin panel it redirects me to index. Can I use `.htaccess` just to visually rewrite this word and everything else into all URLs stays the same? What is the right syntax?

Just:

```
https://example.com/product/simple-product-1
```

To:

```
https://example.com/продукт/simple-product-1
```

and of course all the other products.

Comment: To _visually_ change this URL, you'll need to change this in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

This one is not very simple but there is one way you could do this, with some small limitations.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Check if the request is not coming from the Proxy
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?is_proxy=true(&.*)?$
# Redirect (301) the user to the new location
RewriteRule ^/?product(/.*)?$ /продукт$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite the request with http_proxy including a Query String that we can check
RewriteRule  ^/?продукт(/.*)?$ /product$1?is_proxy=true [QSA,P]

# Common WP rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I tested this on an Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS Server with Apache 2.4.27.

So here are the pre-requisites:

1. You need apache http_proxy enabled otherwise you will get a 500 Server error.
2. We have to add a Query String so that the Rewrite Engine does not end up in an endless loop.
   This Query String could be anything you like but choose something that has no meaning to your WP Site like the UTM parameters from Google. My example: `is_proxy=true`. The Query String won't be seen by the user, but if you chose something that WP recognizes you could get some unexpected behavior.

Please also read the sections below on how to secure your server if you use mod_proxy:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html and
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#access
- Using mod_proxy will cost some performance:
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you `register_post_type()`, you can pass in a `rewrite` parameter in the arguments to rewrite this. No need to manually write regular expressions or anything.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type